# Regular expression to parse data

Tags: regex, parsing

I need help in my regular expressions I need to parse two types of data:

```
card =   AP-1 
port1 =  GSX-A-X4  
port2 =  OLT-1-1 
port3 =  GSX-A-4
```

For card i have `^\w+-(\d+)$` and for port `^\w+-(\d+)-(\d+)$` i believe port will be the same for all 3 port scenarios?

Comment: How about this? `^\w+-(\w+)(?:-(\w+))?$` (to make the last part `-xx` optional)

Comment: Your port regex fails on `port1` and `port3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression `^\w+-(\d+)-(\d+)$` matches only 1 port.

I don't know the constraints of the values you try to match, but my guess for the ports could be
`\w+-([A-Z]?|\d+)-([A-Z]?\d+)`

For quickly examining a regular expression with lots of test values, I suggest using Scriptular:
[image]

Comment: Thanks that help it is a great tool.

Comment: Here is what i used for port `\w+-([A-Z]?|\d+)-([A-Z]?|\d+)\d$`